# how to properly exit a function that is applied in a conditional function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to exit from an initial function if this function output returns a certain object.

Here's the initial function:

```
def some_random_fun(state):
    i=0
    
    while i < 100:
          i+=1
          set_state=state

          if set_state is None:
             print('Set state is none at trial {}'.format(i))
             is_none=True
             
             if i==100:
                print('iteration is done')
                break
          else:
                is_none=False
                print('state is not none')
                  
                return state, is_none
```

Then I evaluate the initial function output inside another function, the idea is that as `state=None`, this function has to just `exit()` without any further message of error or anything.

```
def print_states():
    state, is_none=some_random_fun(state=None)
    
    if is_none is False:
        print(state)
        print('is none, done!')
    else: 
        exit()

print_states()
```

However when applied the next message arises:

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

What am I missing?

How could I set `print_states()` to just exit in this case?

Comment: If `some_random_fun()` exits due to reaching `i==100`, it doesn't return anything - yet you still try to unpack its return value into `state` and `is_none`.  You need a `return` statement to handle that case, too.

Comment: Your assignment `state, is_none = some_random_fun(…)` expects that the function returns **two** values. But it returns only **one** value (namely `None`) when it leaves the loop, so no `return` statement is executed.